Ruby on IIS 10 with HTTP Platform Handler
I had Ruby with Redmine on IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019 with HTTP Platform Handler https://qiita.com/alokrawat050/items/d757b23a063435a2619c Helicon Zoo does not support Windows 2019. Now I am reinstalling damaged server. It needs Web Platform Installer, but now it is not available. So I had crashes of Application Pool.
I commented out Web Platform Installer in c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\administration.config and copied inetsrv folder content from working duplicate server except Config folder. Now Application Pool does not crash, but I have errors in Event Viewer with '-2147023829' error of HTTP Platform Handler and in browser I have 502.3 Bad Gateway error with httpPlatformHandler 0x8007042b error.

are you saying that you tried to move the base IIS configuration from an older version of IIS onto a newer server? don't do that. the application configuration should be pretty portable, but anything in the \inetsrv directory should be manually verified and reconfigured for the current version of IIS and whatever runtime. also if your tooling explicitly tells you its incompatible with your platform, and its community does not have any further information, there there is likely little you can do about it.

@FrankThomas No, not older, there are two duplicate servers with Windows 2019 in three-head cluster. Now one of them needs to be reinstalled. Thanks for your comment!
